# I want to update my listview once i add data in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Hi every one I am working on SQLite.when i add the data listview doesnt get updated

```
String[] from = { helper_ob.FNAME, helper_ob.LNAME };
        int[] to = { R.id.tv_fname, R.id.tv_lname };
        cursor = adapter_ob.queryName();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
        nameList.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

here I am inserting the data to SQLite.

```
public long insertDetails(String fname, String lname) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.FNAME, fname);
        contentValues.put(openHelper_ob.LNAME, lname);
        opnToWrite();
        long val = database_ob.insert(openHelper_ob.TABLE_NAME, null,
                contentValues);
        Close();

        return val;

    }
```

i am following 
http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-sqlite-and-listview-example.html this given tutorial .
Any suggestion is appreciated.

But when I run same code 2nd time it shows added data.

Comment: `notifyDatasetChanged()` Use this line right after the code where you add new data in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not clear, at what stage of the view creation you are loading the data. Its worth you try calling the notifyDataSetChanged after loading the data. Its basically notifies the attached list that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

```
 cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks it works for me when i wrote function to onresume istated of onCreate.:)